# show popup dialog box in asp net using js not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

i want to show popup dialog box in asp net using js but it not working!

here is my code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The behaviour: when i click the button, the popup dialog not shown and the page become disabled(gray shadow).
when i remove ( class= "modal"), it shown put also everything is disabled!!!

Comment: That code is working just fine. You probably have some custom javascript and/or css interferring with the bootstrap Modal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js in the view or the main layout?